# Im trying to get combobox data from the identifications of list ids in SQL Server but get a retrieving error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to get combobox data from the identifications of list ids in SQL Server:

```
private void AddProductsScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!this.IsUpdate)
        {
        }

        LoadAllSizesInDataGridView();
        LoadDataIntoComboBoxes();
}

private void LoadDataIntoComboBoxes()
{
    ProductCategoryComboBox.DataSource = GetComboBoxData(3);
    ProductSupplierComboBox.DataSource = GetComboBoxData(2);
}

private DataTable GetComboBoxData(int listTypeID)
{
    DataTable dtrecords = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApplicationSetting.ConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_ListTypesDataIntoComboBox", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListTypeID", listTypeID);

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dtrecords.Load(sdr);
        }
    }

    return dtrecords;
}
```

The issue is I'm getting all the names in datagridview of sizes and in combobox it is showing `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to Configure the combobox control with value and display member with data table column names:

```
ProductCategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
ProductCategoryComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```